# bootstrap navbar search embedded ruby

Tags: ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, navbar

I have this code for a search bar in my nav bar.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search an Artist">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I want it to correlate to this embedded ruby code

```
<%= form_tag(artists_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Artists" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to just remove the div class ="form-group" and submit button and then put the ruby code within the form class, but then it changes the look of it and will only work when I'm already on my artists page, I want it to work from anywhere on my site. Any suggestions on how to integrate the ruby code into the html one?

Comment: If you need to apply the same styling then you will require the div that are containing your form, I don't know the structure but this is how it mostly works, what you can do is apply the same class to your button and let me know if it works.
`<%= submit_tag "Search", class: :'btn btn-default',:name => nil %>`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<%= form_tag(artists_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", html: {class: 'form-group'}) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Artists", class: "form-control" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => 'btn btn-default',:name => nil%>
<% end %>
```